# IOS 5 show custom Items on Lockscreen

Tags: ios, api, ios5, lockscreen

[APP Advice](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2011/10/two-new-apps-make-ios-5-even-more-amazing-%E2%80%93-and-we%E2%80%99ve-got-promo-codes) presented two apps, ["Slide To Buy"](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/id465684775?affId=1777033) and "Slide To Do", that show interactive items on lockscreen.

What API is used to display that items?

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct control over the lock screen, so I suspect that they're just push (or perhaps local) notifications.

Notifications allow you to open the app they came from, so the "swipe to check off" functionality is basically just launching the app. Quite clever but it's not using any fancy or unknown APIs.